# When I do user.file.attach(params[:file]) it doesn't save when using active storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, rubygems, rails-activestorage

I'm getting this error with the line @user.file.attach(params[:file]):

ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved in UsersController#runFile.
Failed to save the new associated file_attachment.

I am using active storage to store files.

In my User model I have this code:

```
has_one_attached :file
```

in my Users Controller,
I have this code:

````
def runFile 
```
  @user.file.attach(params[:file])
```
end

```
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:file)
end
````

in my form in views I have this code:

```
<%= form_with(model: user, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited 
              this user from being saved:</h2>

     <ul>
      <% user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

   <div class="field">
     <%= form.label :file %>
    <%= form.file_field :file %>
  </div>
 <br> 

  <h6 class="actions">
    <%= form.submit "Create" %>
  </h6> 
<% end %>
```

This is my show form as for each user you click Run File for the runFile method:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
    <%= link_to "Run File", runFile_path, method: :post %>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(@user) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', users_path %>
```

Comment: I also have @user.save in the runFile method

Answer (score 0):

I think you have mixed a few things.

To display a form, you need a normal link (without `method`). In your case, it will be `runFile`. However, `runFile` is responsible just for displaying the form. You need another method that will handle the action of submitting the form. Similar to `edit` and `update` methods.

Here is an idea of how it might look:

```
def runFile_form
  # do whatever you need to display the form
end

def runFile
  @user.file.attach(params[:file])
end

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:file)
end
```

In routes, please define a GET route for `runFile_form` method and use it on the show page:

```
<%= link_to "Run file", runFile_form_path %>
```

Comment: there's a new error now -- I guess maybe :file is empty so is there something wrong with what I did in the views

Comment: @sr1 can you please update your question with the code of the entire form?

Comment: would the runFile_form method call runFile and if not where would it be called? Also would this fix the issue of the new associated file_attachment not saving?